# Ebean run native SQL queries with list of arguments

Tags: hibernate, ebean

I need to use Ebean to run native SQL queries like this:
http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlQuery.html

But how can I express 'not in' syntax to set parameter?

Comment: @PaulHicks I was stuck because I don't know how many ids I am gonna get. I think I can set the variable names dynamically. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`not in` should work fine directly in the SqlQuery.

```
select col1, col2 from tbl where col3 not in ( :val1, :val2 )


sqlQuery.setParameter("val1", 7);
sqlQuery.setParameter("val2", 42);
```

You can also pass a list as a parameter:

```
select col1, col2 from tbl where col3 not in ( :valList )


sqlQuery.setParameter("valList", listOfValues);
```